# Prove that the Following Graph Has $p F^2_p$ Spanning Trees

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, algebraic-combinatorics

I am working on *Algebraic Combinatorics* by Richard P. Stanley.

Problem 4 on Chapter 9 reads:

Let $p \ge 5$, and let $G_p$ be the graph on the vertex set $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with edges $\{i, i+1 \}$ and $\{i, i+2 \}$, for $i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus, $G_p$ has $2p$ edges. Show that $G_p$ has $pF^2_p$ spanning trees where $F_p$ is the $p$th Fibonnaci Number (assuming that $F_1 = F_2 = 1, F_3 = 2, \cdots$).

This chapter deals with the Matrix-Tree Theorem. The main formulas provided in this chapter are:

1. The Matrix Tree Theorem (to count the number of spanning trees)
2. The Laplacian Graph of a regular graph of degree $d$ can be expressed as: $$L(G) = dI - A(G)$$ where $I$ is the identity and $A(G)$ is the adjacency matrix.
3. If $G$ is a connected graph on $p$ vertices and the eigenvalues of $L(G)$ are: $$\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots \lambda_p$$ where $\lambda_p = 0$, then the number of spanning trees in $G$ is: $$\frac{1}{p} \prod_{i =1}^{p-1} \lambda_i.$$

I tried working with the Laplacian matrices and the Adjacency matrices and tried using all $3$ of these formulas but was unable to find any patterns.

I feel like Binet's formula is going to be important here in order to represent the Fibonacci Numbers however none of the eigenvalues that I have seen so far seem even somewhat related to the terms in Binet's Formula.

How should I attack this problem?

Comment: is p a prime? ${}{}$

Comment: No. The book does not specify so I'm assuming that it can be any integer  greater than or equal to $5$.

Comment: You can get the eigenvalues because the matrix is circulant but I seem to get stuck after that. the non-zero eigenvalues are:

$$-4+ \omega^i + \frac{1}{\omega^i} + \omega^{2i} + \frac{1}{\omega^{2i}} \qquad i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$$

Comment: yeah - it was very ugly. I'm trying to work with the Laplacian Matrix minus the last row and column. However, after doing that, the matrix loses its circulant nature. Could you think of a way to find the eigenvalues of such a matrix? EDIT: I'm doing this because while working with the entire matrix, if we come across something like $p = 7$, then the eigenvalues will have extremely ugly notations (because of the roots of unity). Hopefully by getting rid of the row and column, we can circumvent these roots of unities.

Comment: Oh, good Idea, but it may be better to just get the determinant of those things inductively

Comment: How might an induction argument work? How do you induct on the size of the matrix? Is there a way to size a determinant from an $n \times n$ matrix to a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix?

Comment: You use the formula where you go over one of the rows and add the determinant of the smaller graph (the one without the row and column) although it may get messy. You would get 4 summands I believe

Comment: I don't think I've learned that formula. Is there a name for it? Or alternatively, could you please send a link explaining how to use it?

Comment: I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451941/need-help-calculating-this-determinant-using-induction It seems that an induction argument could work? There's very few non-zero terms in the matrix.

Comment: I don't know if it works, I need to get my notebook

Comment: From what I see, that recursion works for tridiagonal matrices. Once you remove the last row and column, our Laplacian matrix is also tridiagonal EXCEPT it has a $-1$ in the top right and top left. Do you know of some way to work around that?

Comment: Sorry I'm stumped

Comment: As you can see the solution isn't very straightforwad (in fact the one I found has a couple of gaps but I think one can work through them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwja5u7arOjvAhUDKKwKHU4MCjwQFjAAegQICBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.math.washington.edu%2F%7Ereu%2Fpapers%2F2017%2Fmichael%2Fcirculant.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1JjAf_DgUH_sCQCrGzP-dN).

Summary of the solution in case the link rots: First solve for the "unhooked" graph in which the edges $(p-2,0),(p-1,0)$ and $(p-1,1)$ are removed. ( we get $f_{2n-2} = f_n^2-f_{n-2}^2$ such graphs ). Notice that by rotating this "unhooked" graph that is contained in the circulant one we can get $n(f_n^2 - f_{n-2}^2)$ distinct subtrees. And then in order to get the remaining $n(f_{n-2}^2)$ subtrees do some shenanigans with rotation yet again.